# How to upgrade from OS X 10.6.8 to Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, upgrade, osx-mountain-lion, mac-app-store

My Mac died and I needed to reinstall. I tried to restore from my Time Machine backup, but that also crashes for me (no idea why). So I've reinstalled OS X 10.6 (Snow Leopard) and ran all the updates, so I'm on 10.6.8.

I want to get Mountain Lion back (which I'd previously bought from the Mac Store), but I can't run the App Store to get it: When I try to load it I get a message:

> You have OS X 10.6.8. The application requires 10.7 or later.

What can I do?

Comment: So, you can't run the Mac App Store itself? You got the App Store through System Update, right?

Comment: What version of the App Store application are you using? I suspect the version you are using is too new. My copy of Snow Leopard has App Store 1.0.2, and can download Mountain Lion...

Comment: I ran the system update to get 10.6.8. That didnt put app store in the usual menu place (under the apple), but I can find it from spotlight. And when I run it, I get the message I described.

Comment: @Scot thanks, how can I tell what version of app store? and can I get the right version somehow?

Answer (score 1):

App Store should be located at this location:

```
/Applications/App Store
```

so, open the Applications folder, select the App Store application, and select "Get Info" under the "File" Command in the Finder. If it is not 1.0.2, or if the App Store app is located elsewhere, I suspect it is misinstalled. Try redownloading the [10.6.8 combo installer](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1399), apply it, then retry the App Store...

Comment: Actually, I'd run the combo updater even if the App Store is the right version -- *some*thing is weirdly wrong, and installing the combo update has a reasonable chance of fixing it.